# What class of word are "to" and "past" in "ten past two", "five to three" etc

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, time

When talking about times,

- 5:30 can be read "half past five"
- 5:40 can be read "twenty to six"

etc.

What is the name of this type of word: to or past, in that context?

I'm not sure if it's "conjunction", I'd hope there a more specific word.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to) actually lists this usage of at least 'to' under 'prepositions'. It adds the rider '[used as a] function word', which might just mean that unlike lexical words such as 'dog', 'slowly' it's hard to form a mental picture of the idea that the word actually conveys, or it could mark for non-prototypical ie not spatial) usage (to[wards] the beach).

Comment: "Past" and "to" are essentially idioms when used in this sense.  They are syntactically equivalent to "after" and "until" and should be regarded as prepositions.